How to Adjust Key Value Size and Font Size for Alignment in SAS Visual Analytics 2024.07
I am working with SAS Visual Analytics version 2024.07 and need assistance in adjusting the key value size for proper alignment. Additionally, I would like to customize the font size to better suit my visualization requirements.
Here are the specific details of my issue:
Objective: To align key values properly and modify the font size to ensure readability.
Challenges:
I am unable to locate the settings or options to change the key value size.
I am not sure if the font size customization is available for this version or if there’s a workaround.
Where can I find the setting to adjust the key value size in SAS Visual Analytics 2024.07?
Is there a way to customize the font size of key values? If so, could you please provide a step-by-step guide?
Any advice, documentation, or examples would be greatly appreciated.
